# Merge tifs into a single file renamed

Tags: bash, tiff, batch-rename

I would like to merge several tif files into one *and* name the new, multipaged, file automatically.

Let's say I have these files:

```
tif65465_001.tif
tif65465_002.tif
tif65465_003.tif
```

I would like to obtain:

```
tif65465.tif
```

(so removing the last 4 characters).

I am using `tiffcp` but it seems to not like batch feeding.

This command produces a bash error:

```
for f in *.tif; tiffcp "$f" "$(basename "$f" .tif).tif"; done
```

...and I have no idea you to use bash to remove the last 4 characters.

Comment: `tiffcp *_*.tif tif65465.tif`

Comment: Ok but the purpose is to batch process the renaming and apply to a lot of files with different names (but all with the last 4 character in the form of "_001").

Answer (score 3):

I presume you actually have multiple documents with multiple pages, not just the single document of 3 pages you say.

So, to rebuild each document from its constituent pages, iterate over the documents using just the first page:

```
for f in *_001.tif; do 
   base=${f%_*}
   echo Processing $base
   tiffcp $base* $base.tif
done
```

Or, as a one-liner:

```
for f in *_001.tif; do base=${f%_*}; tiffcp $base* $base.tif; done
```

Comment: My .tif are single paged (1 page for each tif and I want to merge them into a mulitpage document). But your command works anyway (I just replaced *_001.tif by *.tif). I have a message "TIFFFetchDirectory: Can not read TIFF directory count. TIFFReadDirectory: Failed to read directory at offset 483556." but I obtain a multipage tiff anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

```
 $ name="tif65465_001.tif"
 $ echo "${name%_*}.tif"
 tif65465.tif

 $ tiffcp "${name}" "${name%_*}.tif"
```

Put all the above into a `for loop`

```
 for name in *_001.tif
 do
     tiffcp "${name%_*}"*.tif "${name%_*}.tif"
 done
```

Comment: with this, tiffcp will be launched only on the file tif65465_001.tif (not on the tow other _002 and _003). I will not have multipage toff output.

Comment: sure. You just need to put those into a `for loop`. See my updated answer.

Comment: There was an extra "*" (I edited the answer) but even with the correction, I obtain a empty tif file (with the correct name).

Comment: ok it works but I have the same message than the other answer: `TIFFFetchDirectory: Can not read TIFF directory count.
TIFFReadDirectory: Failed to read directory at offset 483556.`